# Codeigniter if controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

First of all sorry if its a noob question.

But is it posibble to do this in codeingiter, like if i have a sidebar but i only want to load it in 2 pages

```
if(controller == 'blog') {
   //load sidebar
}
```

just like in wordpress if is_page

Comment: I dont quite understand why not just load the sidebar in the relative functions on your controller or just put the sidebar in the blogs views?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$this->router->fetch_class()`

```
if($this->router->fetch_class() == 'blog') {
   //load sidebar
}
```

Also `$this->uri->segment(2)` will work in most cases, but in some cases like `mod_rewrite` or when using `subfolder` or `route` it may fail.

Comment: in case of use in pages.php file what to do for that ??

i want to add if condition for only abot page to modify $data array.

Answer (score 0):

More simply you can do like this.

```
$controller_name = $this->CI->router->fetch_class();
if($controller_name === "your_controller_name")
{
 //your logic
}
```